# Is there a tool for registering 32 bit COM classes for use by 64bit through the COM surrogate

Tags: c#, com, registry, 32bit-64bit

We have some C# assemblies that can be registered using RegAsm and accessed from VBA using 32bit Excel

If we use 64bit Excel then we need to add registry entries e.g.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID\{F103997A-4B60-44BB-8935-AC85704A7960}]
"DllSurrogate"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{F103997A-4B60-44BB-8935-AC85704A7960}]
AppID="{F103997A-4B60-44BB-8935-AC85704A7960}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{F103997A-4B60-44BB-8935-AC85704A7960}]
AppID="{F103997A-4B60-44BB-8935-AC85704A7960}"
```

This seems to be enough to make it work, but we wanted to know if there was a tool that can generate the registry entries, and also remove them in the same way as RegAsm register/unregister

Comment: Instead of a surrogate like that, you could use the one provided by COM+ component services: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cossdk/com--application-overview it's fully programmable and also offerts a bunch of additional services (pooling, recycling, etc.)

Comment: If you compile them for MSIL (as opposed to x86 or x64), then you can use regasm to register the same assemblies for both 32-bit and 64-bit. The trick is you use the 32-bit regasm to register for 32-bits and you use the 64-bit regasm to register for 64-bits. The 64-bit regasm is generally in c:\windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319 or wherever yours is.

Comment: Unfortunately the 32 bit code still relies on other 32 bit elements, we are working towards Any CPU, but not there yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no tool to generate the COM surrogate entries to enable 64bit Excel to talk to 32bit COM.

I wrote a simple tool to generate the .reg file and this is used by the installer.

When our class ids/prog Ids change, a new .reg file is generated